# LAN over RF link leads to intermittent errors

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

We have an odd error occurring with our network, the setup is:

```
IP Camera -> Radio LAN repeater -> Local switch -> PC
```

The IP camera is streaming video over RTSP / UDP and we can control it from a client on the PC or via a browser. All works fine when the setup is:

```
IP Camera -> LAN cable -> Local switch -> PC
```

But we see errors when the radio link is in the chain. Commands (sent as HTTP POST to the camera) are sometimes missed and the video stream is visibly choppier.

**Here's the curious thing:** What we DON'T see is *any errored packets*, we only see HTTP POST messages rejected by the camera as being malformed.

The radio link consists of two boxes which are effectively transparent to the network, pretty much as if there was a LAN cable there (or so they claim), and we have two different types from different manufacturers exhibiting similar behaviour.

We have Wireshark with a tap on the local switch (port mirrored), and if we put a switch with a wireshark tap on the camera end that does not see any bad packets either. That setup looks like this:

```
IP Camera -> Switch -> Radio LAN repeater -> Local switch -> PC
               ^                                 ^
               |                                 |
             WS TAP                            WS TAP
```

So, we can see no bad packets at either end (tap), with the switch in the way the signal *must* be being regenerated / repeated by the switch so that rules out the first couple of layers.

If it helps the switches are Netgear ProSAFE PlusSwitch.

I'm a little lost as to what to check / try next, this seems like the sort of thing someone here might have seen before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems like an error in the web server code whereby it wasn't handling fragmented requests - another PITFA chalked up to those pesky Elbonian code slaves.

Far too much hackery has gone on to post a solution here that would be of any use/interest to anyone not using this particular Elbonian SDK but the gist of it was to buffer an entire request before passing it to the buggy handler code.